# Excel 2007 vba range.find method can't locate cell containing: 8" (2 chars long, pronounced: 8 inches)

Tags: vba, excel, find, excel-2007, quotation-marks

In a particular 1-column-wide range in a spreadsheet I need to use Excel 2007 VBA's `range.find` method to locate a text-valued cell containing the 2-character long value:  8"  (pronounced in the US as Eight Inches).  The `.find` method is in a sub that works fine for all other searches it's doing, but it cannot seem to find 8", or in fact any text value with a trailing double-quotation mark.

In the code below, initially `sComparisonText` contains `8"`

I've tried adding from 1 to 6 double-quotation marks to the end of `sComparisonText`, using `Chr(34)`, but the .find method still returns Nothing.

Various searches have noted the `Chr(34)` approach, and also stacking double-quotation marks:  `""""` resolves to `"`, `""""""` resolves to `""`, etc.  I've also looked into the `.find` method having a specialty escape character, but no success there either.

```
If Right(sComparisonText, 1) = """" Then
    sComparisonText = sComparisonText & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(34)
End If
Set rResult = rCT.Columns(InputColumn).Find(What:=sComparisonText, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If (rResult Is Nothing) Then  'Add a new row to the bottom of the rCT range
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much!
Dave

Comment: Just checking if there's a typo here - if you said sComparisonText initially contains (8"), you're not stripping off the final (") but instead adding 6 more double quotes, for a total of 7?

Comment: Hi Andrew,  You are correct, I'm not stripping the final ("), just adding more to it.  I've tried (desperation) adding from 1 to 6 (") characters, but nothing I've tried will make the .find method actually find the cell.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear why you are trying to escape something that isn't a string literal.  The reason you need to escape double-quotes in a string literal is so the ***compiler*** can parse it.  The `.Find` function only expects a single `"` if you are only looking for a single `"`.  If you already have a string stored in a variable that contains `"` in the string, use that.  If you need to add one to a string, you can either use `Chr$(34)` or the escaped string literal `""""`. They give you exactly the same resulting string:

```
Dim sComparisonText As String
Dim rResult As Range

sComparisonText = 8 & Chr$(34) 
Set rResult = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=sComparisonText, LookIn:=xlValues, _
              LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
              SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
Debug.Print rResult.Address
```

...is the same as...

```
sComparisonText = "8"""
Set rResult = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=sComparisonText, LookIn:=xlValues, _
              LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
              SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
Debug.Print rResult.Address
```

...is the same as...

```
sComparisonText = 8 & """"
```

...etc.

The escape sequence has no meaning outside the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to consider is using **xlPart** rather than **xlWhole**

The second thing is to verify you really have double-quotes rather than a pair of single quotes.  Click on the miscreant cell and run:

```
Sub WhatIsInThere()
    Dim st As String, msg As String
    Dim i As Long, CH As String

    st = ActiveCell.Text
    msg = Len(st)
    For i = 1 To Len(st)
        CH = Mid(st, i, 1)
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & CH & vbTab & Asc(CH)
    Next i
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

To see an example of finding something with a trail double-quote, start with an empty worksheet and run:

```
Sub EightInchNails()
    Dim DQ As String, WhereIsIt As Range
    DQ = Chr(34)
    Range("A15").Value = "8" & DQ

    Set WhereIsIt = Range("A:A").Find(what:="8" & DQ, after:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

    If WhereIsIt Is Nothing Then
    Else
        MsgBox WhereIsIt.Address(0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) I though xlPart would match a cell with more content than just the search string, whereas xlWhole required the match to be with the entire contents of the cell.  Functionally, I need the later.  Have I misunderstood the use of the constants xlPart and xlWhole?     2)  Your WhatIsInThere() utility worked great!  It reported pretty much what we'd expected:  a 2 character long string, 1st char = ASCII 8 or Decimal 56, and the 2nd char = ASCII " or Decimal 34.

Answer (score 0):

```
range.find "8"""
```

Should do the trick. The first two quotes at the end escape the actual `"` character, and the third quote terminates the string.

Comment: Your suggestion works!  I can use it hard-coded into the range.find as you've shown above.  I can also use the string constant "8""" to set a variable which is then used in the range.find line:   `sComparisonText = "8"""`.  Unfortunately, what I can not make work is to take the original contents of `sComparisonText` (the 2 chars: 8") and have vba add a leading double quote and a pair of trailing double quotes.  The value shown in the watch window appears correct (although surrounded by and extra pair of quotes as the watch window always does).

Comment: Assuming that sComparisonText starts with the value '8"': `sComparisonText = """" & sComparisonText & """"""` Escaping quotes in VBA is kind of weird.